# Mysql, select rows from a field value AND from id value

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the table:

```
  id  |  name
------+---------
  10  |  val1
   3  |  val1
   5  |  val1
   4  |  val2
   1  |  val2
   6  |  val3
   8  |  val3
   7  |  val3
   9  |  val3
   2  |  val4
```

The table is ordered by value column and I've to preserve this order

How can get all the rows after id=8 and name>val3 with this result?

```
  id  |  name
------+---------
   8  |  val3
   7  |  val3
   9  |  val3
   2  |  val4
```

I've tried with query like:

```
SELECT FORM table WHERE id>8 AND VALUE name>'val3'
```

but obviously is not the result i looking for... any idea?

**Edit 1:**

Sorry but it isn't possible change the design of the db, and let me say that I think it's hard to say how a db is designed from a general table used to explain only a specific problem. However, yes i know the query is wrong but I need all the rows after value of the second column and FROM a certain id value... it's a bit more clear?

**Edit 2:**

When I say FROM a certain id value, i'm not talking about cardinal order of the id column, but i'm talking about the position after that with the id value specified

**Edit 3:**

Ok... I've a table ordered by name column, how can I select only last n rows? I can use eventually an id value (8 in this case) and a name value (val3 in this case)... i know it's unusual...

**Edit 4:**

Ok i've rewrite the question in a better way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31067619/mysql-get-all-rows-for-a-next-page-having-only-the-last-record-of-the-previous) this question is not usefull anymore please close it, thankyou for the time you've spent anyway

Comment: is that a typo? I see `value` twice in your query

Comment: Your database is poorly designed.

Comment: sorry now the column is called name

Comment: @mikeb it's only a situation that i've found

Comment: Your instructions are very unclear. I have no idea why id 2 is included. Or 7, for that matter. And why not 6?

Comment: Based on edit 2, you're trying to do something very dangerous here. Order of rows should not matter inside of a database. There is no consistent ordering in your sample data, so I have no idea how/why you've picked the values you have.

Comment: Even if your table is ordered by name, the id column isn't ordered by anything, so what you're doing is really impossible. How do I know 7 comes after 8? I can't assume that it's in decreasing order, because then 9 comes after 7. There is nothing consistent enough to grab here.

Comment: @McAdam331 because i need name value major or equal val3 (supposing that val2<val3<ecc...) and i've to get these rows from id=8

Comment: I understand that, but if you consider how this looks to a computer, the computer has no idea 7 is supposed to come after 8, and 9 is supposed to come after 7. That's not consistent, so I'm not sure you can even add a position variable.

Comment: And this is the problem... how can get rows using only the second column? starting count from id=8?
It's that the main problem

Comment: Did you come to a solution? If so you should share it and mark it as accepted. If not you should mark the helpful answer as accepted so that it helps future visitors

Answer (score 0):

@mikeb in the comments is correct. Consider changing the design of your database.

If that's not an option and you only have this data. Plus your sample data is incorrect too. You want the value with `id = 2` and `id = 7` in your output however you say you want `id>=8` (you said `id>8` but I wonder why you wrote the row with `id=9` in the sample output).

If you only want

> How can get all the rows after id>=8 and value>val3 having with this result?

you can do something like this

```
SELECT id, name
FROM table 
WHERE  id>=8 AND  name IN ('val3','val4')
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend coming up with a consistent order to your table. Let's say you want to order by name and then id, like this:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM myTable
ORDER BY name, id;
```

Once you have that, you can use a variable to build a position:

```
SET @position := 0;

SELECT id, name, @position := @position + 1 AS position 
FROM myTable 
ORDER BY name, id;
```

Given that table, you can select all rows after the position for row 8 by using a subquery to determine that position, like this:

```
SELECT tmp.id, tmp.name
FROM(
  SELECT id, name, @position := @position + 1 AS position
  FROM myTable
  ORDER BY name, id) tmp
WHERE tmp.position >= (somePosition);
```

To determine some position, you can use the following subquery:

```
SELECT position
FROM(
  SELECT id, name, @position := @position + 1 AS position
  FROM myTable
  ORDER BY name, id) tmp
WHERE id = 8;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/490aba/9) example.

Note that this will only return 8, 9, and 2 because as I mentioned at the beginning you need a consistent order. There is no way to write a query, given your data, to know that 7 should come after 8.

Comment: That is not the desired output though. It also gives the row `10  |  val1`

Comment: Your desired output is inconsistent. See my comment under the question.

Comment: I agree but it was as OP stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last n rows of something, do an order by desc and then limit `n`.

Based on the tables you gave, you can do:

Example:

```
select *
from table 
WHERE name > 'val3' 
order by name desc, id desc
limit 4;
```

This will give you only rows where name > `val3` and order them like this (it orders the name first in descending order and then the id's in descending order):

```
 id  |  name
------+---------
   2  |  val4
   9  |  val3
   8  |  val3
   7  |  val3
   6  |  val3
```

and the limit 4 will just give you the first 4 rows of that:

```
 id  |  name
------+---------
   2  |  val4
   9  |  val3
   8  |  val3
   7  |  val3
```